# How do I find out which system.info my site is using?

Tags: 7, updating

I have 3  sites using the same host. I have updated them from 7.89 to 7.91 however only one site shows as using 7.91. I have hunted my host files for a system.info with 7.89 without any luck.

Where do I find which system.info files are being used by my sites?

Answer (score 1):

The Drupal 7 Core version is in `includes/bootstrap.inc` on line 10, not in a `.info` file. Example:

```
define('VERSION', '7.91');
```

Comment: See my comment below. That is the system.info that my sites should be using (I think).

Answer (score 1):

The [*system.info*](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.info/7.x) file is simply the file containing information for the *System* module. As such, there should not be more than a *system.info* file in a Drupal site, except in the case you copied the Drupal core files more than once.

The *system.info* file doesn't contain any release value. It just contains a reference to a constant defined in another file.

```ini
name = System
description = Handles general site configuration for administrators.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x
files[] = system.archiver.inc
files[] = system.mail.inc
files[] = system.queue.inc
files[] = system.tar.inc
files[] = system.updater.inc
files[] = system.test
required = TRUE
configure = admin/config/system
```

[`VERSION`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/constant/VERSION/7.x) is defined in the *includes/bootstrap.inc* file. If that file has been updated, it's probable the Drupal core release isn't reported correctly.

Comment: This is what is in my system.info in the /public_html/modules/system folder. name = System
description = Handles general site configuration for administrators.
package = Core
version = VERSION
core = 7.x
files[] = system.archiver.inc
files[] = system.mail.inc
files[] = system.queue.inc
files[] = system.tar.inc
files[] = system.updater.inc
files[] = system.test
required = TRUE
configure = admin/config/system

; Information added by Drupal.org packaging script on 2022-07-20
version = "7.91"
project = "drupal"
datestamp = "1658334256"

Comment: This is VERSION in bootstrap.inc       /**
 * The current system version.
 */
define('VERSION', '7.91');